# How to print enum names instead of int value of a protocol buffer (Java)

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

The default toString prints the int value instead of the enum name.  Is there an *easy* way to make it print the enum name instead?

Comment: Your first sentence is not correct.  `toString()` returns the name of the constant by default.  If you are using something that overrides `toString`, you can get at the name by using `name()` instead.

Comment: Are you using the `enum` class? If so, someone else has overridden your `toString()` method. The behavior is to print the name of the value: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

Comment: To people who are responding, Raymond is probably talking about Enum's in protocol buffers !!!

Comment: To @Raymond, please tell us how are you accessing protocol-buffers, When you generate java, it should generate a standard Java-Enum which toString() = Enum-Value. Are you DynamicMessage or Lite-Messages or something other than standard Protocol Buffers. Some code would be useful as well ???

Answer (score 8):

(Answer is for [**proto3**](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3))

Use Carl's enum example:

```
enum Foo {
  BAR = 1;
  BAZ = 5;
  QUX = 1234;
}
```

Suppose you have variable: `Foo foo = Foo.BAR`, to get the name of `foo`:

```
String fooName = foo.getValueDescriptor().getName(); //fooName="BAR"
```

Also see:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#enum

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.EnumDescriptor#getName()

Answer (score 0):

For the following protobuf enum:

```
enum Foo {
  BAR = 1;
  BAZ = 5;
  QUX = 1234;
}
```

The docs say that:

```
An integer constant is also generated with the suffix _VALUE for each enum value.
```

It sounds like you are using the the constant "e.g. BAR_VALUE, BAZ_VALUE, or QUX_VALUE".  Is this the case?

See: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#enum

Answer (score 0):

You could get a list of the enum values using `.values()` in java.

Assuming you had a protobuf enum

```
enum Foo {
    BAR = 1;
    BAZ = 2;
}
```

If you referenced Foo from Java, you could get an array of Foo's values with `Foo.values()` - or if you were using a generic enum for the call, `genericEnum.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()`.

This would give you `[BAR, BAZ]`.